# microsoft sql server authentication on linux

Tags: java, sql, database, linux, windows-authentication

I am using integrated security provided by sqljdbc4 which uses sql_auth.dll to authenticate a user to access the database. This of course works fine on my windows machine but when deploying to Linux enviornment I recieave the error below. During the time of development I over looked the fact that a dll was used which can't be used on non window OS'. Is there any way of doing a similar authentication on the linux machine. This is a web application developed in java, and I can't use an username or password to connect to the database this is the sole reason I have been cornered into using windows-authentication. A little about my environment. Java 1.6; Tomcat 7.0.23; Maven project

I have came across the existence of JDBC-ODBC but I haven't been able to come across how to properly set up the drivers or the jar files or what ever is needed for it to work properly with a java application. If this is the preferred or proper way of going about this task please provide me some insight

Thank you.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1722)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:835)
>       at com.sdge.evis.common.dao.impl.AccAccountDaoImpl$1.doInHibernate(AccAccountDaoImpl.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
>       ... 42 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2329)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
>       ... 57 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
>   Blockquote